# How do I subtract two dtype datetime64[ns] using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to do a dynamic extraction from an Excel, after I generate that excel I now have to create a new column that is going to subtract one date that is in there with my current time and do that for all the rows.

I already changed the dtype of the date because it was a string like this:

```
   df['DateAction'] = pandas.to_datetime(results['DateAction'])
```

And confirmed that it was datetime64[ns] so now i was thinking of doing something like this :

```
for index, row in results.iterrows():
    df['Name of the table is going to generate']=df['DateAction']- mycurrent time
```

To point out that the date in the excel is like this "24/03/2021  13:13:21"

I don't know what to put in my current time cause i already tried a lot of things and sometimes I get errors in my log function like "--  unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'type'"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```py
pd.to_datetime("now")
```